# Use font-awesome in mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks

Tags: c#, wpf, font-awesome, modern-ui

My question is pretty simple, I want to override font for Modern UI title links. Here's what I did so far:

```
<mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
  <mui:Link x:Name="lnkSettings" Source="/Pages/SettingsPage.xaml">
        <mui:Link.DisplayName>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbFontAwesome" Text="&#xf004;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="32" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        </mui:Link.DisplayName>
  </mui:Link>
</mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
```

But I'm getting XML parse error. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can not put a textblock or any other element inside a link. You can just change the text of the link.